# How do I perform a fold operation on a sequence of Failures

Tags: scala, exception, functional-programming, monads

We have some legacy code in our codebase that is eventually going to be refactored to use Validated and Either from Cats library. This is because Validated does not use fail-fast mechanics. The unrefactored code uses fail-fast mechanics of Try monad.

Since the refactoring hasn't happened yet, I am doing a kludgy hack to get around the fact that the Try monad is fail-fast. I am having trouble implementing it however.

I basically have a list of type Try[T] that is guaranteed to all be Failures.

I am trying to aggregate all of the error messages of all the Failures into a single Failure.

Here is the function I am refactoring:

```
  private def extractTry[T](xs: IndexedSeq[Try[T]]): Try[IndexedSeq[T]] = {
    val failures = xs.collect { case Failure(ex) => Failure(ex) }
    if (failures.size > 0) failures.head
    else Success(xs.map(_.get))
  }
```

Instead of failures.head in the second line of the method, I want to aggregate all the Failures.

So something like

```
if (failures.size > 0) failures.foldLeft(Failure(new IllegalArgumentException(""))){case (Failure(acc), Failure(e)) => Failure(new IllegalArgumentException(acc.getMessage + e.getMessage))}
```

The only thing I don't like about this implementation is that I would like each step of fold not to use IllegalArgumentException, but to use the new element's exception type. So the idea is to keep the exception type of the last element in failures, and not to use an arbitrary exception type.

We are planning to eventually use Either[Throwable, T] in place of Try and will probably run into the exact same problem there when we try to aggregate errors. We want to keep the exception type and not assign an arbitrary one like IllegalArgumentException. So this problem is going to have to be solved sooner or later, and I would prefer that it be sooner.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with those exceptions?

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez We want to keep the exception type in the Failure because we eventually pass that Failure to a Future which when completed will be used to complete a route in Akka Http. Depending on the exception type, we use a different error code. So NoSuchElementException is 404 and IllegalArgumentException is 400. That's why we need to keep the exception type.

Comment: In that context, how does aggregation should work? You can not return multiple error codes.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez That is true. During aggregation, where we have an accumulator and a new element, the result will have the exception type of the new element. So if I am aggregating over a chain of Failures, it will only keep the exception type of the last Failure. This is just a heuristic to decide on the error code. Of course, we would like it if we could display all the relevant error codes to the user, but http protocol of course only allows us to display one.

Comment: I think the best on the long run, would be to create your own **ADT** for representing errors, and create your own **Semigroup** for it. Then, when you refactor to **Validate**, you will have everything done.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking that for the refactoring to Either, instead of Either[Throwable, T] we should use Either[CustomErrorType, T] so that aggregating using the Semigroup or Monoid can accommodate the rules I have described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, we would follow suggestion by @Luis. Until then consider perhaps something like so

```
sealed trait OverallResult[+T]
case class OverallError(accumulatedMessage: String, finalErrorCode: Int) extends OverallResult[Nothing]
case class OverallSuccess[T](xs: IndexedSeq[T]) extends OverallResult[T]

object OverallResult {
  /**
   * Aggregating over a chain of Failures, it will only keep the exception type of the last Failure.
   * This is just a heuristic to decide on the error code. Depending on the exception type, we use
   * a different error code. So NoSuchElementException is 404 and IllegalArgumentException is 400.
   */
  def apply[T](xs: IndexedSeq[Try[T]]): OverallResult[T] = {
    val failures = xs.collect { case Failure(ex) => ex }
    if (failures.nonEmpty) {
      val accMessage = failures.map(_.getMessage).mkString("[", ",", "]")
      OverallError(accMessage, errorCode(failures.last))
    }
    else OverallSuccess(xs.map(_.get))
  }

  private def errorCode(ex: Throwable): Int = ex match {
    case _: NoSuchElementException => 404
    case _: IllegalArgumentException => 400
    case e => throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception. Fix ASAP!", e)
  }
}

OverallResult(Vector(Try(throw new NoSuchElementException("boom")), Try(throw new IllegalArgumentException("crash"))))
OverallResult(Vector(Try(42), Try(11)))
```

which outputs

```
res0: OverallResult[Nothing] = OverallError([boom,crash],400)
res1: OverallResult[Int] = OverallSuccess(Vector(42, 11))
```

Note explicit documentation of the heuristic mentioned in the comments:

```
/**
  * Aggregating over a chain of Failures, it will only keep the exception type of the last Failure.
  * This is just a heuristic to decide on the error code. Depending on the exception type, we use
  * a different error code. So NoSuchElementException is 404 and IllegalArgumentException is 400.
  */
```

Error accumulation is simulated with

```
failures.map(_.getMessage).mkString("[", ",", "]")
```

and overall status code decided with

```
errorCode(failures.last)
```

Now clients of `extractTry` need to be refactored to pattern match on `OverallResult` ADT, and `finalErrorCode` instead of exceptions, but lower level codebase should remain unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Mario wrote up a response that I think deserves being the accepted answer because of its thoroughness. It was while reading his answer that I stumbled upon another solution that requires less code change, but still gets the job done.

The answer is to pattern match on the exception type, which seems very obvious in retrospect.

```
if (failures.size > 0) failures.foldLeft(Failure(new IllegalArgumentException(""))){case (Failure(acc), Failure(e)) =>
  val message = acc.getMessage + e.getMessage
  e match {
    case ex: IllegalArgumentException => Failure(new IllegalArgumentException(message))
    case ex: NoSuchElementException => Failure(new NoSuchElementException(message))
  } 
}
```